# Excel - How to reference a cell, within a formula, located immediatley to the right of a value returned by a MIN Function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

New to the community. I am attempting to use within a formula, a value within one of two possible cells that are located immediately to the right of two cells, the contents of one of which will be chosen by a MIN function. The cells that the MIN function is acting on are on the same row, but not contiguous. Hence my issue looks something like:

=MAX(F8,M8)+SUM(G8,N8)-MIN(F8,M8)+ {*the Cell contents to the right of F8 or M8 dependant on the MIN Function result*

I've tried using the CELL, INDEX, and MATCH functions together to return the cell reference for the minimum contents, as a starting point, and then attempt to offset the cell reference to the right by one, but it won't work for a non-contiguous range. Anyone got any ideas.  Thanks all.
D.

Comment: It would really help if you could show what the worksheet looks like exactly, right now it's a bit of a guessing game.

Answer (score 0):

People forget that you can use IF in the middle of another mathematical statement:

```
=MAX(F8,M8)+SUM(G8,N8)-MIN(F8,M8)+IF(F8<M8, G8, N8)
```

Or rather

```
=MAX(F8,M8)+SUM(G8,N8)+IF(F8<M8, G8-F8, N8-M8)
```

Or rather

```
=MAX(F8,M8)+IF(F8<M8, 2*G8-F8+N8, 2*N8-M8+G8)
```

Or rather, in most efficient form:

```
=IF(F8<M8, 2*G8-F8+N8+M8, 2*N8-M8+G8+F8)
```

Now, this works only if by immediately to the right of F8 is G8 and of M8 is N8. The problem you are alluding to is, if for instance you insert a new column next to F or M. The cells to the right would still be G and N but the formula would auto update G8 to H8 and N8 to O8. To circumvent this, you can use OFFSET (not using the efficient form for clarity):

```
=MAX(F8,M8)+SUM(G8,N8)-MIN(F8,M8)+IF(F8<M8, OFFSET(F8,0,1), OFFSET(M8,0,1))
```

Note, using OFFSET in a large workbook could slow down your computer considerably. OFFSET is a volatile function and will recalculate the whole time.

You could also use e.g. INDIRECT("G"&ROW()), which would always resolve to say G8 regardless of column inserts or cell moves and copies. Unfortunately INDIRECT is also volatile!  Also if you inserted a new column F, the formula would now compare G and N and should actually return H and O.

The preferred way would be to use INDEX, which is non-volatile. I think this should work but haven't tested it:

```
=MAX(F8,M8)+SUM(G8,N8)-MIN(F8,M8)+IF(F8<M8, INDEX(F8:G8,1,2), INDEX(M8:N8,1,2))
```